# how do I use jsonb_array_length with condition?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My table, `t`, has a nested jsonb_object, `ss`.  Below is an example of a single record:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "ss":[
    { "ss_id":1, "approved":true },
    { "ss_id":2, "approved":false },
  ]
}
```

How can I count the number of objects in `ss` where `approved = true`?

I can get a count of all objects in `ss` using `jsonb_array_length()`, but have been unable to apply a filter to the count.

```
SELECT
  id,
  jsonb_array_length(t.ss) ss_cnt, -- returns total count
  jsonb_array_length(
    CASE WHEN t.ss -> 'approved' = 'true' THEN t.ss END
  ) a_cnt, -- returns null
  ss
FROM t
```

For context, my end goal is to create a bool indicator of whether all objects in `ss` have a value of `"approved":true`.  This is the intermediate step to make that evaluation, but am open to other approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unnest array elements with `jsonb_array_elements():`

```sql
select id, value
from t
cross join jsonb_array_elements(ss)
where (value->'approved')::bool
```

Use the boolean aggregate function `bool_and` to check whether all elements of an array has `"approved": true`

```sql
select id, bool_and((value->'approved')::bool)
from t
cross join jsonb_array_elements(ss)
group by id
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=987253c7d9cc68e94423583db87141e4)

Read in the docs:

- [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)
- [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: perfect! I have null values in some cases, so just needed to coalesce those to false before using `bool_and`